# Chrome reports e.key = undefined for Del key

Tags: javascript

I notice that Firefox returns e.key = "Del" to the keydown handler when the Del key is pressed but Chrome returns e.key = undefined. Both return e.keyCode = 46.

Isn't there a standard way to report key pressings?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this one for size:

```
var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
```

Some browsers use `which` and others use `keyCode`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe using the "keyCode" property is the standard for these types of events.

Hope that helps!